# NodeJs - Access a Passport session's UserId in SocketIO

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, passport.js

I'm writing a NodeJS solution which relies on Passport for authorisation and SocketIO.

When a socket connection is accessed I want to be able to fetch the users session/profile which is stored in MongoDB if there is one. (Through connect-mongo).

I have implemented Passport.socketio to access this from the Store.

```
io.set('authorization', passportSocketIo.authorize({
        passport: require('passport'),
        cookieParser: cookieParser,
        key:         'connect.sid',       
        secret:      'StackSecret',
        store:       new store({
            db: mongoose.connection.db,
            collection: 'sessions',
        }),

        fail:        FailedMethod
    }));
```

I can then access the user's profile from "socket.handshake.user"..

```
socket.on("callback", function(){
     console.log(socket.handshake.user); //Fetch Logged in user's Id
})
```

This would work perfectly if I was trying to block access to the socket but I want it to be open to every connection (Both with a session or not). I just want to be able to access their Passport session Id if they are logged in.

What is my best way of accessing a sessions userId from SocketIo?

I'm hoping Passport.socketio is overkill and I can do it easily without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the fact that posting a question often helps you answer it!

The fail Method takes 4 parameters data, message, error, callback.

You can fire the call back with a success true and it will continue without authorisation.

```
function onAuthorizeFail(data, message, error, accept){
    accept(null, true);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your own answer would probably suffice for this case, but you answered a more general question (how to access session info for a socket connection). The following is how I do it generally. Additionally, I normally register all the routes in such a way that they get a reference to a config, so I can also provide every request handler with a socket connection specific to this particular session:

```
var cookie = require("cookie"),
    parseSignedCookie = require('connect').utils.parseSignedCookie;

var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
    if (socket.handshake.headers.cookie) {
        var cks = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);
        var sessionId = parseSignedCookie(cks["connect.sid"], config.sessionSecret);

        config.sessionStore.get(sessionId, function(err, session) {
            if (!err) {
                console.info("connected socket for ID " + sessionId);
                config[sessionId] = socket; // set socket to config so that request handlers could emit on it

                socket.on("disconnect", function() {
                    console.info("disconnected socket for ID " + sessionId);
                    delete config[sessionId];
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

For the request handlers to know about the config I write them normally in the following form:

```
exports.get = function(conn, config) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        var socket = config[request.sessionID];
        if (socket) {
            // socket.emit 
        }
        res.end();
    }
}

app.get("/", someModule.get(customConnection, config));
```

For the latter, see more under https://github.com/codelab-io/node-route-dir

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I think an approach like this might be worth looking into. This approach would only look for the cookie when the connection is initially made though? In my case the authorisation will often take place after the connection is created.

Comment: on("connectiion" will happen any time when the client-side code containing io.connect is reloaded (e.g. page reload or any standard request). If user changes happen without reloading that bit one needs to dig deeper, such as emit something on the connection and move this logic into hadler for that event :) In fact, for me it works anyway: I am only getting sessionId from the socket, not the whole user. I process the user and store it in the session-store by a separate middleware.